# I'm trying to print the names of the blobs in a container

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to print the name of the blobs in a container, however nothing prints after the line

```
            List<BlobItem> segment = await blobContainer.GetBlobsAsync().ToListAsync();
```

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using System.Linq;
namespace IterateBlobs
{
    /*Main code for iterating over blobs*/
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task iterateBlobs = IterateBlobsAsync();
        }
        private static async Task IterateBlobsAsync()
        {
            String connect = "connection string";
            BlobServiceClient sourceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connect);
            BlobContainerClient blobContainer = sourceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container name");
            // Iterate through the blobs in a container
            List<BlobItem> segment = await blobContainer.GetBlobsAsync().ToListAsync();
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in segment)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name + " ");

                BlobClient blob = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
                // Check the source file's metadata
                Response<BlobProperties> propertiesResponse = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();
                BlobProperties properties = propertiesResponse.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Your code does not await for `IterateBlobsAsync`, so `Main` returns before the first network request has a chance to receive response. Try changing `Main` to be `async Task` and just adding `await` for the `IterateBlobsAsync()` function call.

Comment: Also, does it even compile? `GetBlobsAsync().ToListAsync()` - this specifically. `ToListAsync()` works with `IQueryable`, `GetBlobsAsync` returns `IAsyncEnumerable` and is supposed to be used with [`await foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was able to get it to print the blob names.To your last comment, I did have trouble making it compile , but I installed System.Linq.Async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad that you have fixed the issue.

Thanks @[n0rd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31782/n0rd) posting your suggestion as an answer so that it will be beneficial to other community members.

If you are iterating the ***Blob containers and files*** you have to use the **async Task**.

In your code you are iterating the blob containers but in a main block it doesn't **wait for all iteration to complete**. It will return once get any response from **`IterateBlobsAsync`**. It will ***exit from the main*** methods that is the reason you are not getting any container information.

To avoid this, you have to follow the below

#### Modified Code

```cs
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task iterateBlobs = await IterateBlobsAsync();
        }
        private static async Task IterateBlobsAsync()
        {
            String connect = "connection string";
            BlobServiceClient sourceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connect);
            BlobContainerClient blobContainer = sourceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container name");
            // Iterate through the blobs in a container
            List<BlobItem> segment = await blobContainer.GetBlobsAsync();
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in segment)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name + " ");

                BlobClient blob = blobContainer.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
                // Check the source file's metadata
                Response<BlobProperties> propertiesResponse = await blob.GetPropertiesAsync();
                BlobProperties properties = propertiesResponse.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=environment-variable-windows#list-the-blobs-in-a-container) to list the blob containers.